# Programmatically training NER Model using .prop file

Tags: java, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I have been to train my ner model using a property file as shown in the tutorial here [LINK](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a). I am using the same prop file but, when I fail to understand as to how to do it programmatically.

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment, regexner");
props.setProperty("ner.model", "resources/NER.prop");
```

the prop file is as shown below :

```
# location of the training file
trainFile = nerTEST.tsv
# location where you would like to save (serialize) your
# classifier; adding .gz at the end automatically gzips the file,
# making it smaller, and faster to load
serializeTo = resources/ner-model.ser.gz

# structure of your training file; this tells the classifier that
# the word is in column 0 and the correct answer is in column 1
map = word=0,answer=1

# This specifies the order of the CRF: order 1 means that features
# apply at most to a class pair of previous class and current class
# or current class and next class.
maxLeft=1

# these are the features we'd like to train with
# some are discussed below, the rest can be
# understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
# word character ngrams will be included up to length 6 as prefixes
# and suffixes only
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useDisjunctive=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
# the last 4 properties deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

Error :

```
 java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 23206C6F
....
..
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't load classifier from resources/NER.prop
```

From another question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601875/how-to-use-serialized-crfclassifier-with-stanfordcorenlp-prop-ner), I understand you provide the model file directly. But, how can we do that with the help of a property file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run this command from the command line:

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop NER.prop
```

If you want to run this in Java code, you could do something like this:

```
String[] args = new String[]{"-props", "NER.prop"};
CRFClassifier.main(args);
```

The .prop file is a file specifying the settings for training your model.  Your code is attempting to load the .prop file as a model itself, which is causing the error.

Doing either will generate the final model at resources/ner-model.ser.gz

Comment: This I understood from the FAQs. But, how can we generate that model file from the property file?

Comment: If you run the command as specified with the .prop file you made it will save the model at resources/ner-model.ser.gz ... you can also call the main method() of CRFClassifier in Java code, though that is not recommended

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TrainModel {
private void trainCrf(String serializeFile, String prop) {
    Properties props = StringUtils.propFileToProperties(prop);
    props.setProperty("serializeTo", serializeFile);
    SeqClassifierFlags flags = new SeqClassifierFlags(props);
    CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> crf = new CRFClassifier<>(flags);
    crf.train();
    crf.serializeClassifier(serializeFile);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String serializeFile = "skill/ner-model.ser.gz";
    String prop = "ner.props";
    TrainModel trainModel = new TrainModel();
    trainModel.trainCrf(serializeFile, prop);
}
```

}